# Combinatorics: separating 20 people into 2 groups of 10.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a group of 20 people there are three brothers.  The group is separated at random into two groups of 10.What is the probability that the brothers are in the same group?

My idea is that this is the same probability as choosing a single group of 10 with two cases: the count of three people chosen plus the count of three people not chosen = $\frac{{}^{17}C_7+{}^{17}C_{10}}{{}^{20}C_{10}}=4/19$, but the answer from the textbook is $2/19$. Can someone explain the flaw in my logic?

Comment: You only need to choose for other 7 members from 17 remaining people. By selecting 7, you already select 10 to be in the other group.

Comment: @Brian $P(\text{all in first group}) +P(\text{none in first group})$ is not wrong.

Comment: @DanielMathias: You’re right; I misunderstood what the OP was thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book’s answer is wrong: the correct answer **is** $\frac4{19}$. Here are two ways to calculate it.

To make a split that has all three brothers in one group, we need only choose $7$ of the other $17$ to fill out their group; the remaining $10$ people will form the other group of $10$. There are of course $\binom{17}7$ ways to do this, so there are $\binom{17}7$ ways to split the $20$ people into two groups of $10$ with all three brothers in one of the groups.

Of course we need to divide this by the number of ways to split the $20$ people into two groups of $10$. This is **not** $\binom{20}{10}$: that counts each split twice. A split into groups $A$ and $B$ gets counted once when we select the $10$ people in $A$ from the $20$, and it gets counted a second time when we select the people in $B$. Thus, the correct denominator is $\frac12\binom{20}{10}$, and

$$\frac{\binom{17}7}{\frac12\binom{20}{10}}=\frac4{19}\,.$$

Alternatively, let the oldest brother be George. In any split of the $20$ people into two groups of $10$, George has to be in one of the groups. The other $9$ people in that group can be any $9$ of the remaining $19$ people, so there are $\binom{19}9$ ways to form a group of $10$ that includes George. This method counts each split into two groups of $10$ once, since it distinguishes the group that contains George, so the probability of getting a split with all three brothers in one group is

$$\frac{\binom{17}7}{\binom{19}9}=\frac{4}{19}\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you exclude the three brothers while making a group, the other group will contain all the three brothers. Thus, the number of cases where one group contains all the three brothers is $^{17}C_7$, and the probability is
$$\frac{^{17}C_7}{^{20}C_{10}} = \frac{2}{19}$$

Comment: Your denominator counts each split twice, so your answer is too small by a factor of $2$.

Answer (score 0):

First 3 brothers are in the same group, the number of cases is $\binom{17}{7}$

And second group can be chosen in $\binom{10}{10}$ different cases from remaining people

$   \frac{{{}^{2}C_1}{}^{17}C_7\times{}^{10}C_{10}}{{}^{20}C_{10}\times{{}^{10}C_{10}}} =\frac {4}{19}$

You have already chosen 10 people so you have to choose second group from 10 people (not 20), and multiply the number of different cases (not add).

Finally,   ${{}^{2}C_1}$ cases for choosing one of the groups for three friends,  because there are 2 groups and the question do not specify which group the friends must be in.

Comment: Your denominator counts each split twice, so your answer is too small by a factor of $2$.

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott : Thanks for all, informed me about labeled or unlabeled groups.

Comment: You’re very welcome.